# Excel process left after vbs script

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am running a batch file which calls a vbs script to open a workbook, execute a macro (which calls several subs and functions), creates an email and displays it, saveas a version of the workbook, and then close down the workbook and close down the process.
For some reason after execution, the workbook will close, but I will still have a blank excel process running regardless of what I do.  Everything else is working fine aside from the lone process that gets stuck running.  How do I get rid of the ghost instance I end up with?  Why am I getting stuck with an excel process?

**Batch Script Calling the VBS Process:**

```
cscript update.vbs "C:\Test\Batch\AutoUpdate\Summ.v1.xlsm"
```

**VBScript:**

```
Dim args, objExcel

Set args = WScript.Arguments

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)

objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "NewRunAll"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Quit

set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

**VBA Save Down Process in Book :**

```
Public Sub SaveDownBook()
    'Saves down a copy of the entire workbook
    Dim filePath As String, fileName As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo saveDownBook_bailOut

    filePath = Sheet7.Range("copy_filepath").Value
    fileName = Sheet7.Range("historical_filename").Value

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (filePath + fileName)

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

saveDownBook_bailOut:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Error Description: " + Err.Description)
        MsgBox ("Error Number: " + Err.Number)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to remove the objects in the reverse order they are created, which means you have to save each object in a variable when it's created. Kill the Worksheet object, then the Workbook object, then the Workbooks collection object (most people forget about that collection object) and then the instance of excel.

Comment: @braX Could you elaborate a little further?  I don't ever substantiate a workbook object or a worksheet object in my code do I?  I'm simply using active Workbook and referring to a sheet name?

Comment: BraX means that some of the methods you call create and return an object (such as `Workbooks.Open`. Store these objects in a variable and close them explicitly, otherwise Excel thinks they still being used. E.g. `Dim wb : Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(args(0))` so that you can now call `wb.Close()`

Comment: Alternatively, for the above example, simply call `objExcel.Workbooks.Close(yourbook)`.

Comment: In addition to closing them, set them to `Nothing` and run a garbage collection at the very end.

Comment: @braX VBS doesn't have a garbage collector you can invoke, it's implicit.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven I have followed the instructions above and am still ending with an open excel process.  What could I possible be missing?

Comment: Dunno. Take out you statements one by one from the inside out and figure out which one is the culprit?